# Manipulating particular values of a previous tensorflow layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to build a tensorflow model in which the final output is a decaying function of the original data and the classifier.

Thus, I've got the following layer:

```
class HalfLifeLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(HalfLifeLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def call(self, inputs):
        return tf.exp(-inputs[:,5]/inputs[:,0] - inputs[:,6]/inputs[:,1])
```

and the following setup:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Concatenate
from tensorflow.keras import Model

I = Input(shape=(None, 6))
d1 = Dense(8, kernel_regularizer='l2')
d1 = Dense(8, kernel_regularizer='l2')
d1 = Dense(8, kernel_regularizer='l2')(I)
d2 = Dense(8, kernel_regularizer='l2')(d1)
d3 = Dense(8, kernel_regularizer='l2')(d2)
d4 = Dense(2, kernel_regularizer='l2')(d3)
# A
c = Concatenate()([d4, I])
hl = HalfLifeLayer()(c)
model = Model(inputs=I, outputs=hl)
# B
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryFocalCrossentropy(), optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam())
model.fit(fit_data, fit_labels, validation_split=0.1)
```

Then I get an error:

```
ValueError: Can not squeeze dim[0], expected a dimension of 1, got 32 for '{{node binary_focal_crossentropy/weighted_loss/Squeeze}} = Squeeze[T=DT_FLOAT, squeeze_dims=[-1]](Cast)' with input shapes: [32].
```

I think this should be equivalent to removing the code between `# A` and `# B` and instead doing

```
output = tf.exp(-I[:,3]/d4[:,0] - I[:,4]/d4[:,1])
model = Model(input=I, output=output)
```

but this gives a different error:

```
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "tf.math.truediv_12" (type TFOpLambda).

Dimensions must be equal, but are 6 and 2 for '{{node tf.math.truediv_12/truediv}} = RealDiv[T=DT_FLOAT](Placeholder, Placeholder_1)' with input shapes: [?,6], [?,2].

Call arguments received by layer "tf.math.truediv_12" (type TFOpLambda):
  • x=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 6), dtype=float32)
  • y=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 2), dtype=float32)
  • name=None
```

It doesn't seem to be recognizing the dimensions of my data or neurons correctly. How would I resolve this problem?

Comment: `Concatenate` is a class not method. You need to call like `Concatenate()([d4, I])` or if you use  method then do `concatenate([d4, I])`  (though not it doens't ensure that your code will work. Try this, if face error, please give reproducible code.

Comment: Hey @Innat fixed now - sorry about that

Comment: what is the shape of input? Do you intentionally set `(None, 6)` cause you will pass input shape of `(batchsize, something_dynamic, 6)`? Also, the error message says that the shape of target and prediction don't match, where they should. Please add some dummy code to reproduce the issue.